# RequestBuilder and http Authorization header

Tags: http, gwt

How GWT RequestBuider object generate Authorization header ? Does it use user and password ? or it doesn't generate and I've to calculate it? if so, how can I calculate basic authorization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Authorization' header must be set. The server uses the username, and password only if it prompts  authorization.

Answer (score 0):

RequestBuilder uses XMLHttpRequest under the hood, which relies on the browser for authentication. For Basic auth, all you have to do is provide the user and password. Note that you won't have control of auth errors, in case the credentials are wrong the browser will ask the user with its own UI.

Comment: But when I try to fetch rb.getHeader("Authorization"); it gets null ! although I set user and password